# Sorting answers by votes dates

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, sorting

Is there some mechanism that sort answers depending on the date the upvotes were given? Most of the time an answer that got 500 upvotes this year is better than one that got 1000 upvotes ten years ago.

Comment: well, read both answers, test them and you will know which one is better for *you*

Comment: Upvotes don't indicate anything other than popularity.

Comment: Post vote datetime information hasn't been publicly available through a SO page since they reworked the Post Timeline page several years ago. So I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 11):

No, there isn't anything like that in the UI. (You could craft a query to get this info if you *really* wanted it, though.)  The best you get in terms of chronological sorting is when the post was made.

Ultimately though it doesn't matter.  If a post is valuable, then people will vote it as valuable.  If you're concerned that you're not getting the most valuable answer, then it's important and imperative for you to read multiple answers so that you can establish which one works best and is most practical.  While there can be a correlation to upvote score and accuracy of answer, **it is not a guarantee**, so you should always look at every answer on a question regardless of how old it is.

Comment: A simple skim can usually tell which answers are more relevant to your specific case, so it wouldn't even be necessary to comprehensively read all of them. Skip, skip, oh this one looks promising - read.

Comment: You'd be surprised.  Dealing with ancient log library configurations that has existed and evolved since the early 2010s can make for some painful afternoons.